# Get x, y, and z rotate axis in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to know how I can get the x, y, and z rotation  in java FX.

I've tried `camera.getRotate()`, but I can't get the x, y, or z rotation degree with it.

Answer (score 1):

[`Camera`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Camera.html) is a [`Node`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html), which is affected by zero or more [`Transform`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Transform.html)'s that you can retrieve by calling [`getTransforms()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms()), one or more of which might be [`Rotate`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html).

Comment: How do I get the degrees that the camera has been rotated by?

Comment: @Lasher Ehh.... `Rotate` property `angle` - Defines the angle of rotation measured in degrees.

Comment: Ok i'll try that